# Books database. ISBN or serial number as primary key

Tags: mysql, database

Am doing a library database and need to store, among other things, the serial number and ISBN of each book. What's the difference between each other? The former has to be unique while the later can be repeated. For example, if i have 3 copies of "My Book" (same format; same publisher; same everything) i would have something like this:

- Serial Number 1; ISBN 11-1111-1111-11; Name My Book.
- Serial Number 2; ISBN 11-1111-1111-11; Name My Book.
- Serial Number 3; ISBN 11-1111-1111-11; Name My Book.

At this point you might say that serial number should be the primary key since it has all of the requirements to be one. And i agree. The thing is, there is another table called "Authors" and since each book can have multiple authors and each author can have multiple books associated, i need a M-M table between both tables (Books and Authors). Let's called it "Participation".

Following the previous idea of primary key for "Books", this "Participation" table would have at least as foreign keys both serial number and some kind of id for the author. And here is my problem. In my head it does not make since that each author has associated, through participation, a serial number when they should be associated to a ISBN, you know, the real-world id of their work.

Is there a problem in db logic? Like changing some keys on Books or Participation. Or am i just overthinking it?

**BTW Am working with mysql.**

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I like my pk to have no meaning beyond the scope of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need a fourth table.

Your table for books should be split into a parent table representing the *idea* of a book, along with a new child table for *copies* of the book, the actual things owned by the library.

The `book` table holds the ISBN number, title, publication date. The `copy` table holds the serial number you mentioned, as well as the date the copy was obtained by the library, the current condition of the book, and a date when the copy left the collection (was lost/discarded/destroyed).

By the way, think through whether you mean that “serial number” to be an ever-increasing count to be used as a primary key or a differentiating factor between copies of the same book.

And, I suggest changing the name of your bridge table from `Participation` to `Authorship` to be more descriptive. And tables should be named in the singular, not plural.

Here is my crude ASCII-art [ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model/).

[author] —1——0< [authorship] >0——1– [book] —1——0< [copy]

Each author has zero, one, or more books for which they did some writing, so zero, one, or more child rows in `authorship` table. Each book has zero, one, or more authors, so zero or more rows in `authorship` table. Zero `authorship` rows for a book means either the author is unknown or that author has not yet been assigned.

Each book when being planned to be added to the collection has zero rows in the copy table. When copies are eventually obtained, rows are added to this table.

Librarians probably have their own terminology that could be replaced here for `book` and `copy`.

You may also have an issue with editions of a book. But I’ll ignore that here.

Tip: Search for “database normalization” to learn more about how to arrange tables in a database design.

Comment: @Strawberry Please explain. Database normalization is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: Conventions for naming stuff are a matter of opinion. To a lesser degree, so is normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry Regarding both your points (naming and normalization), you need to do some study of relational database theory as laid out by [Dr. E.F. Codd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) and [Chris Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date). Normalization is the only area of software development that is certainly *not* a matter of opinion, proven mathematically in papers and books.

Comment: Odd then that we have a concept Normal Forms (plural)